# "This game is not recognized by game center." iPhone Development

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ios4, game-center

There are already a couple of questions on this but I followed their steps to solve it and it doesn't seem to work for me. Here's what I have done:

1. I double checked to have the bundle identifier in the xcode project to be the exact same as the provisioning profile found on the provisioning portal (it also says Game Center is enabled). No wildcards.

2. I have logged in using a sandboxed account to gamecenter (made 2 accounts incase one wasn't sandbox). I did see the word "sandbox" with some numbers/letters on the top left while signing up for an account, so I'm 100% sure I have a sandboxed account. Tried 2 different sandbox accounts. Tried on 2 different devices (ipad/iphone). Also tried on the iPhone simulator.

3. I have deleted my app from my iPhone many times and tried it again.

I'm running 4.3/xcode 4 on iPhone + iPad.
I'm still receiving the message. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From memory (I battled with this recently)…

In addition to what you've already done, you have to setup your app (even if it's using a fake bundle ID) in ITC (iTunes Connect). This means you need to put in a name, category, a screenshot and a bunch of other stuff (you can just put dummy data in there for testing purposes). Then you need to create a version of your app, then enable Game Center on that version.

There might have been a few other important steps that I've forgotten, but in between the voodoo dancing and making sacrifices to the gods of iOS etc., that's all I can recall.

Comment: Ok well I just set up a dummy app application on itunes connect using the same APP ID as the one i'm working on. It's been a few minutes and it's still not working. Will try again later, hopefully this will work.

Comment: ah, i didn't click enable game center. looks like it will work.

Answer (score 9):

Deleting the old app from your device can sometimes help too. Looks like it stores some data with an app and will try to login to actual Game Center instead of Sandbox Mode.
This solved my problem when trying to add Game Center in an update.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved the problem.  I opened the Settings App, then select Game Center.  At the bottom under Developer, turn on "Sandbox".

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Make sure you have the exact same app version in xcode and ITC. For example, if you have 1.0 in xcode and 1 in ITC it will not work. The version is a string not a float, so 1.0 != 1.

Comment: I didn't have a version number listed in XCode, and after deleting and reinstalling the app (answer above), cleaning the project, and setting the version number in XCode, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My situation is , It showed "this game is not recognized by game center",and my ipad is jail-broken. so I uninstall Appsync 5.0+ in Cydia--> logout game center---> reinstall app, it's ok now

Comment: -1 The asker is not developing on a jailbroken device, nor are his primary users.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, almost everything people had suggested was in already correct for my app.

My bundle IDs were correct, my iTunes Connect record was set up, etc. However, the **version number** of the build that had been uploaded to iTunes Connect was not recent (and didn't match the version I was building onto the test device).

After uploading a newer build to iTunes Connect with a matching version number, it appeared to fix the problem.

I'm not guaranteeing it won't break in the future (because the authentication seems to be very flaky and has worked previously, even with the old version record), but for now it seems to have solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

I learned from somewhere that if your machine(iphone or ipad) is jail-broken, it will assume you use the real game center without the sandbox one.

So, if your devices are jail-broken, just restore it, and give it a try.

Hope this will help you.